# Meaning of class file on the file system

Tags: lambda, java-8, method-reference

I'm studying on lambda expressions, the book illustrates an example that uses `toString()` method of lambda expressions.

```
Supplier<ArrayList<String>> s1 = ArrayList<String>::new;
ArrayList<String> a1 = s1.get();
System.out.println(s1);
//Output: functionalinterface.BuiltIns$$Lambda$1/791452441@1fb3ebeb
```

It explains meaning of the output as,

> This actually does mean something. Our test class is named BuiltIns ,
>   and it is in a package that we created named functionalinterface .
>   Then comes `$$` , which means that **the class doesn’t exist in a class
>   file on the file system. It exists only in memory.**

I don't understand the meaning of the last sentences. Could you express it?

Source: [OCP: Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 8 Programmer II Study Guide, Jeanne Boyarsky, Scott Selikoff](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1119067901.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the book is *slightly* misleading. The statement it indeed correct, but with a minor correction. It *assumes* that if you have `$` in a class name it is automatically created (not by you); which might not be a fact.

For example suppose this example:

```
public class TestSO {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test t = new Test() {
      };
   }

   static class Test {}
}
```

You have created an anonymous inner class which is actually a plain class created by the compiler. If you compile `TestSO` you will see a class called `TestSO\$1.class` that was a created for you. If you inspect how it looks with `javap -c -p TestSO\$1.class` you will see something like this:

```
final class TestSO$1 extends TestSO$Test { ...
```

*But* at the same time it is perfectly legal for you to declare a class/method that contains the `$` symbol:

```
static class $$Test2$$ {}
```

So the presence of `$$` is not a strong indication that the class is generated by compiler/runtime. Also that's an implementation detail that could change some day...

Now at the same time the book is correct in the fact that `the class doesn’t exist in a class file on the file system. It exists only in memory`.

`Supplier` is an interface and you have not provided a class that implements it, have you? Well what happens next is interesting.

I am not going to go in a lot of details, but here is a simplified explanation.

If you de-compile your example (`javap -p -c -v TestSO.class`) you will see a line like this:

```
invokedynamic #2,  0  // InvokeDynamic #0:get:()Ljava/util/function/Supplier;
```

What `invokedynamic` does is letting the `runtime` decide how to provide an actual instance of that `Supplier`.  And **at runtime** there is an actual class created that implements that `Supplier` that is used.

You can see how that class looks like with a command used when running it:

```
-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=/Your/Path/Here
```

As a result in that path you will see a class called:

```
TestSO$$Lambda$1.class
```

And again if you decompile it with `javap -c -p  TestSO\$\$Lambda\$1.class`:

```
 final class TestSO$$Lambda$1 
         implements java.util.function.Supplier {....
```

What the author is trying to say is that there will be a `class` generated for you at runtime that implements the Supplier interface, but its not you who have created it.

Comment: Thank you master. It meets my expected answer not half. I like to read your answers always by the way. That's why it is called as anonymous :)

Answer (score 2):

This cite is an attempt to explain something in easier or more colloquial terms, avoiding to be too formal, however, the result can be called disastrous.

The name actually means nothing. The class of the instance provided for a lambda expression or method reference [is intentionally unspecified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4) and so is its name. It is even unspecified whether the `toString()` method which is implicitly invoked when executing `System.out.println(s1);` will produce the “classname@hashcode” output.

Whether file systems are involved or not, is irrelevant. The correct and the actual point is that the class of that instance is not among the classes created by the Java compiler when your application is compiled. Instead, it is provided by the JRE at runtime in an implementation specific way. OpenJDK does provide a generated class that happen to have a name that contains the class containing the lambda expression and a `$$`, but, as said, that’s an implementation detail. And, [as explained by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478299/2711488), the dollar sign is a legal part of Java identifiers, so the presence of two dollar signs doesn’t prove a particular property.

Answer (score 1):

> When you create a class, you type out a `.java` file and compile it to a
>   `.class` file. Both are actual files that exist somewhere on your
>   filesystem. The *`$$`* shows it is different. There is no `.java class` on
>   the filesystem. *Instead Java creates the class for us.* That way you
>   don't have to type out a class and can just supply the lambda
>   expression.

Answered by its author, [Ms.Boyarsky](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeanne-boyarsky-6560351)